# MongoDB can't start when bulking data

Tags: mongodb, crash, pymongo, bulkinsert, database

I insert 2800000 records into mongo by bulking from pymongo, that the mongo suddenly show to me about this error:

```
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 16966 _extentManager.init failed:      InternalError DataFile::openExisting - mmf.open failed, terminating
```

I use ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.
and now, I can't to start mongo.
how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have free space storage on disk?

Comment: yes of course.I have 300 gb space on my storage.
and I have 3 gb of RAM.

Comment: It depends on what data you have there. If it is restorable from other source, you could wipe out MongoDB data directory. And then start  MongoDB. Alternatively you could try to start mongod with --repair option, but nobody guarantees data consistency

Comment: You do realize you are running a 32-bit operating system, so not a good choice for a database server. I presume the number there is the number of records. So how large is the file actually? And how large have your MongoDB datafiles grown to on this import? I also presume this is part of your personal development efforts before this becomes off-topic for this site.